# Rule based styling in Qgis using a combination of attribute(get_feature()) and ILIKE

Tags: expression, rule-based

I Have 2 Layers:

[image]

I want to Filter Layer 2 by an attribute from Layer1 for some rule based styles. I'm currently using following expression to realize that:

*"C1"  = attribute(get_feature(‘Layer 1', 'ID', '1'), 'C') or "C2"  = attribute(get_feature(‘Layer 1', 'ID', '1'), 'C') or "C3"  = attribute(get_feature(‘Layer 1', 'ID', '1'), 'C')… etc.*

It does its job, but due to the amount of features (a few thousands), performance is quite bad.

So I made a new field called "CG" in Layer 2 using following expression in field calculator:

*"C1"  + ' '+ "C2"  +' '+  "C3"  +' '+ "C4"   +' '+ "C5"… etc.*

The Field “CG” I can filter using eg. *“CG” ILIKE “%C1 %”*

**Question:** 
How can I now combine the attribute(get_feature()) and ILIKE expression to Filter the Field “CG” in Layer2 by an attribute of Layer 1 in Field “C” ?  An example would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to solve my Problem.

**Answer:** 
 *"CG" ILIKE '%'+ attribute(get_feature('Layer 1', 'ID', '1'),'C') +' %'*

(space in front of last %)

But it required to add in Field “CG” additional spaces in front of C1 and after C15. For this I used following Expression in the field calculator for the Field “CG”:

**‘ ‘+** "C1"  + ' '+ "C2"  +' '+  "C3"  +' '+ "C4"   +' '+ "C5" +’ ‘+ … “C15” **+’ ‘**